# ListView contentview change from external xml file

Tags: android, listview, resources, listitem

this is what I am trying to do.
I have a listview that is populated from a xml resource file saved in /values/menu.xml

it has this code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string-array name="menuchoices">
     <item name="pv">Present Value</item>
     <item name="fv">Future Value</item>
     <item name="bond">Bond Pricing</item>
 </string-array>   
</resources>
```

So far so simple. Then my Main.java file looks like this: (adapted from other listview questions here)

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuchoices)
            ));


}

public void onListItemClick(ListView partent, View v, int position, long id) {
   if ("pv".equals(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuchoices)[position])){
       setContentView(R.layout.presentvalue);
   }
   }       
}
```

Basically I read that launching new activities all the time is not the best practice so i just told the if statement to change the contentview. The problem is -- Nothing happens when i click on the first item in the list. i also tried substituting "pv" with "Present Value" but it did not help either.

I think this i beacuase i took the code from posts like this here [List View selection to start a new Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420458/list-view-selection-to-start-a-new-activity)) but I don't know how to change it so it works with the external xml resource file.

This should be a simple fix right?

THanks in advance

Max

P.s. all the other stuff works (the presentvalue.xml file is in the layout folder and the list is properly displayed when i run the app)

EDIT //

here is the problematic line

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
   if (view.getText().toString().equals("Present Value")){
       startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, PresentValue.class));
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `onListItemClick()` is typically used with a ListActivity.  There are a couple fixes to this:

1. - Change the line `extends Activity` to `extends ListActivity`.
   - Remove your ListView definition.
   - Change your main.xml id from `@+id/listView1` to `@android:id/list`
2. - add `implements OnItemClickListener` in your class definition after `extends Activity`
   - Change the function `onListItemClick` to `onItemClick`

Try moving your `menuchoices` block:

```
 <string-array name="menuchoices">
     <item name="pv">Present Value</item>
     <item name="fv">Future Value</item>
     <item name="bond">Bond Pricing</item>
 </string-array>
```

Into your string.xml file, then we can simplify your adapter (assuming you did changes #1 above):

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        R.array.menuchoices));
```

We can also condense how you test the menu choice:

```
"pv".equals(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuchoices)[position])
```

Becomes:

```
view.getText().toString().equals("Present Value");
```

(Minor point, you have a typo in the word "parent")

How's that?

Comment: I changed it but still nothing happens when I click on either of the items on the screen. As i said above, the list and everything works great just the onclick does not do anything (nothing appears in logcat when i click something)

Comment: just that i have the error now that

view cannot be resolved

p.s. the typo was here in stack but not in my code

Comment: If your layouts are not too big use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html). But I don't believe that calling `setContentView()` to re-create your layout will work, you can setup a member variable for onCreate() used like this `setContentView(layoutID)`, set `layoutID = R.layout.present_value` in your itemClick function then call onCreate() yourself, but that seems dangerous.

Comment: I have no problem just launching a new activity. Seems easier.

Still what to do about the "view cannot be resolved"?

Comment: Please post you logcat errors and/or the problematic line, so I can see which view cannot be resolved and what's happening.

Comment: i posted the line above in my post. it is a compile error so no logcat. what do i have to put in for          view? The compile error is in the if line

Comment: Oh, either change `View v,` to `View view,` or `view.getText` to `v.getText`.

Comment: ok this is weird... no compile errors anymore but when i launch the app the screen is black. logcat shows following errors
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.mwerner.mycalcfinance2/.Main }
and
ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

weird thing is even when i comment the listener out it still doesnt work .. wtf?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10676/discussion-between-user1012952-and-sam)

Comment: "Bring the app to the front" simply means you trying to run an app that is already running. Easiest thing to do is push back until you're on the home screen. The blank screen suggests the ListView isn't being linked to your adapter, double check the variables.

Comment: hi, here is a link to the rough version of what i have so far. I would copy this style over to the other things and just change what i need. If you could take a look at it and see if a) design or b) tech is bad, please tell me :)

http://d-h.st/IJs

also if you could give me your email, i'd be grateful :)